# How to host a WinForms user control in a wpf user control?

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls, host

i have created a winforms user control and am able to successfully host it in a wpf window using the WindowsFormsHost control.
However when i try doing the same in a wpf user contol, the winforms control won't show up.
Following is the code i am using to host the windows form control using WindowsFormsHost.

```
 <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
 </DockPanel>

 windowsFormsHost1.Child = new WinFormChartUC();
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: I might work if you use a Page rather than UserControl if that is an option.

Answer (score 1):

How about to enclose it fully in WindowsFormsHost element?

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <local:WinFormChartUC x:Name="_WinFormChartUC"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```